# There is no object when rendered

Tags: rendering, animation, 3d-view, filmic-blender

Any clue about this? the object wont render but already appear when using camera mode.

Here is blender file
[image]

[image: Camera mode]

[image: When render]

Comment: You need to have "Show instancer" for viewport in the object settings checked: https://imgur.com/KBCTNko 
Suprisingly -despite being marked as a duplicate- that specific option isn't covered in the linked question.
Aside from that - does the road itself even need to have a particel system?

Comment: ah that works, yes because I have the splash particle when the water goes to road